# Strip out HTML and Exact Special Characters

Tags: php

With the help of friends I've got exact answer for removal of HTML codes and special characters ( Question No.7128856 ~ Thanks to *Mez* ) and here it was the answer

```
$des = "Hello world)<b> (*&^%$#@! it's me: and; love you.<p>";
```

we would remove HTML codes and special characters so by using

```
// Strip HTML Tags
$clear = strip_tags($des);
// Clean up things like &amp;
$clear = html_entity_decode($clear);
// Strip out any url-encoded stuff
$clear = urldecode($clear);
// Replace non-AlNum with space
$clear = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9]/', ' ', $clear);
// Replace Multiple spaces with single space
$clear = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $clear);
// Trim the string of leading/trailing space
$clear = trim($clear);
```

we will get the

**Now I'd like to change the question little bit !**

I'd like to remove HTML codes and certain exact special characters
such as `( ) * & ^ % $ # @ ! ~ _ - + ' " { [ } ]` and so on and only allow all types of letters of whatever even Arabic,Russian,Hebraic ...etc

i found the 1st answer is good but it pass only English alpha-numeric letters Aa-Zz-90 but what for other language such as arabic `عربى` it will consider it as special characters ! and will remove it so my idea is how to define exact special characters !

Thanks

! Can we edit the answer of *Mez* by define which only special characters we remove it

*For who asking Why* ! Cause i'm willing to convert some titles to pure SEO links that is why i'll remove special characters but needs to allow for all languages in same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$clear = mb_ereg_replace( '#[^0-9a-z]#i', '', $clear );
```